# Error 500 Encountered When Uploading Video via LinkedIn API

Tags: python

I need to integrate video uploading on LinkedIn using Python. Could you please provide me with the API key, along with the necessary code and guidance on how to upload a video on LinkedIn?

I tried:

```
def upload_video(access_token, linkedin_page_id, file_size):
    # Step 1: Register Upload
    register_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload'

    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    register_payload = {
        "registerUploadRequest": {
            "owner": linkedin_page_id,
            "recipes": [
                "urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-video"
            ],
            "serviceRelationships": [
                {
                    "relationshipType": "OWNER",
                    "identifier": "urn:li:userGeneratedContent"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    try:
        # Register Upload
        register_response = requests.post(register_url, headers=headers, json=register_payload)
        register_response.raise_for_status()
        register_data = register_response.json()
        upload_url = register_data['value']['uploadMechanism']['com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MediaUploadHttpRequest']['uploadUrl']
        asset_id = register_data['value']['asset']
        
        # Step 2: Upload Video
        with open(file_size, 'rb') as video_file:
            upload_response = requests.put(upload_url, data=video_file, headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}', 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'})
            upload_response.raise_for_status()
            print("Video uploaded successfully!")

        # Step 3: Complete Upload
        complete_url = f"https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets/{asset_id}/completeUpload"
        complete_payload = {}
        complete_response = requests.post(complete_url, headers=headers, json=complete_payload)
        complete_response.raise_for_status()
        print("Upload completed successfully!")

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error uploading video: {e}") and i get  500 error
```

Comment: I think you should read the FAQs https://developer.linkedin.com/support/faq 
API Keys are usually untransferable, so you should generate yours...

Comment: "Could you please provide me with the API key" You are deeply misunderstanding what this venue is for.